# Search facility results PhP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Ok so the problem is very simple, basically when you put for example "W" it should output hotel names and guest's surnames that contain that character. It doesn't that hotel names however it never gives me an output for guest's no matter what I put. There are several matching for guest's that should appear however I get nothing. I can't see any mistakes with my code... Help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="mainpage" value="Main Page" class="submitbut" id="but1" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="searching" />
        <input type="submit" name="data_submit" value="Search" id="scan" />
    </form>

<?php
if( isset( $_GET['mainpage'] ) ) exit( header( "Location: mainpage.php" ) );

if ( isset( $_POST["data_submit"] ) ){

$search_term = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['search'] ) );
$conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 'root' );

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `hotel` h
                        INNER JOIN `booking` b ON h.`hotel_id`=b.`hotel_id`
                        INNER JOIN `guest` g ON g.`guest_id`=b.`guest_id`
                        WHERE `name` LIKE :search_term;");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%' . $search_term . '%');
$stmt->execute();


    echo "
    <table>
    <tr>  
    <th>Hotels Matched</th>
    </tr>";

while($hotel = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td><a href='details.php?name=".$hotel['name']."'>".$hotel['name']."</a></td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `guest` g
                        INNER JOIN `booking` b  ON g.`guest_id`=b.`guest_id`
                        INNER JOIN hotel ON b.`hotel_id`=h.`hotel_id`
                        WHERE g.`last_name` LIKE :search_term;");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term', '%' . $search_term . '%');
$stmt->execute();

    echo "
    <table>
    <tr>  
    <th>Guests Matched</th>
    </tr>";

while($hotel = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td><a href='details.php?name=".$hotel['first_name']."'>".$hotel['last_name']."</a></td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$conn = NULL;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your form method is GET ( <form action="index.php" method="post">) but your index is POST (if ( isset( $_POST["data_submit"] ))

Comment: It's get for the button but there is another form for text box and button<form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="searching" />
        <input type="submit" name="data_submit" value="Search" id="scan" />
    </form>

Comment: Use only one form for all your inputs you want to get posted. Otherwise will be empty.

Comment: well all the inputs are in one form so it's the text box and submit button, above it I only have a hyperlink but that needs to be GET

Comment: remove or comment out the first form and try again, and let us know if there is any error, also you can always wrap the button around the link like this <a href="yoururl"><input type="button" value="Mainpage"></a>

Comment: Just tried it out, even if remove first form it still only gives me an output for the first table and no results for second table :( it's the worst nightmare where you don't get any error messages, when i put echo $search_term; in 2nd while loop it doesn't echo it, so it seems it just never runs that while loop

Comment: I am getting a little confuse, are you trying to get 2 different table result from a single search term?

Comment: Yes, so basically if you input "W" it should search "hotel" table and match hotel names and after that search throught "guest" table and match guest's surnames and then output all the results. Then if I click on either hotel name or guest surname it should take me to another page which contains all the details about that hotel and guest's details or other way round, so the hotel search works but guest search doesn't

Comment: so now the hotel search works after edit, replicate it on guest search and u r done.

Comment: well yeah that's what i mean it looks correct for me so I wonder why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

With PDO Prepared statements with LIKE prepare FULL literal first.See [**PDO Wiki**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)
ie.

```
$name = "%$name%";
```

I have simplified your code using one query. I have tested it on 2 tables, you will need to JOIN other table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="searching" />
    <input type="submit" name="data_submit" value="Search" id="scan" />
</form>
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$username="XXXX";
$password="XXXX";
$database="XXXX";
function writeTable($host,$database, $username, $password,$search_term) {
//Create query
    $sql = "SELECT hotel.name AS hotel, guest.name AS guest
        FROM `hotel`
        LEFT JOIN `guest` ON hotel.guest = guest.id
        WHERE hotel.name LIKE ?
    OR guest.name LIKE ?
";
$html = '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">'. "\n";
//array for column names
$columnNames = array("hotel","guest"); 
//table header
$html .= '<tr>';
foreach ($columnNames as $value){
    $html .= '<th>' . $value . '</th>';
}
$html .= '</tr>'. "\n";   
// connect to the database  
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $hotelname, $password);  
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
//Prepare and execute query 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($search_term,$search_term));
// setting the fetch mode  
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
//Add content
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['hotel'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '<td>' . $row['guest'] . '</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>'. "\n";
}
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
// close the connection
$dbh = null;
}  

$search = strip_tags(trim($_POST['search'] ) );
if(isset($search) ){
    if ($search != ''){
        $search_term = '%'.$search.'%';
    }else{
        $search_term ='';
    }

}   
writeTable($host,$database, $hotelname, $password,$search_term);

?>
```

You should be able to modify to suit.

Comment: Ok I will give it a go and update once I make it work